# Python script inside Online PowerBI Pro

Tags: powerbi

I have read some tutorials about the Python integration inside Power BI reports. This tutorials works on Power BI Desktop.

I have only tried on online version of Power BI (power BI pro). The "P" icon is avaiable in visualization tool box but it does not show me python prompt in the bottom of the screen.

I suppose python is supported on Power BI pro because the icon is present ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

The python editing experience is limited in the Web service, as well as other report creation tools.

You use Power BI Desktop to create your report which has the Python editor and access to the Python installation on your PC. Once created you load it to the service, then it will work. You may need to use a Personal Data Gateway if you are using a Python script in Power Query.

Limitations are outlined here:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/python-visualizations-in-power-bi-service/

Pro doesn't replace desktop, the device is mainly used for collaboration and sharing, as it has limited report editing and creation tools and can only link to a limited number of data sources.